# Modular forms over $\mathbb{Z}$ vs modular forms with integral Fourier coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

It is well known that the ring of modular forms over $\mathbb{C}$ is $$
\mathbb{C}[c_4,c_6]
$$ where $$
c_4 = 1+240 q + \cdots,\qquad
c_6 = 1-504 q - \cdots
$$ are the standard Eisenstein series, and the discriminant $$
\Delta= q - 24 q^2 + \cdots 
$$ satisfies $$
c_4^3-c_6^2=1728 \Delta.
$$

You can use elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Z}$ to define modular forms over $\mathbb{Z}$, and then the resulting ring of integral modular forms is known to be given by $$
\mathbb{Z}[c_4,c_6,\Delta]/(c_4^3-c_6^2-1728 \Delta),
$$ cf. [Deligne après Tate](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0097583).

My question is as follows:

You can instead consider a subring of $\mathbb{C}[c_4,c_6]$ containing modular forms over $\mathbb{C}$ whose Fourier coefficients (in $q$) are all integers. Clearly this subring includes $\mathbb{Z}[c_4,c_6,\Delta]/(c_4^3-c_6^2-1728 \Delta)$. Is it known/shown/easy to see that they are actually equal?

Comment: The search keyword is "q-expansion principle". See e.g. the paper "p-adic properties of modular schemes and modular forms" by Katz.

Comment: Here is another reference for algebraic modular forms which I found really helpful: Katz, $p$-adic interpolation of real analytic Eisenstein series, Ann. of Math. 104 (3), 1976, 459--571.

Comment: Once you have decoded the definitions, it's elementary that any modular form (of level 1) over $\mathbf{Z}$ has integer $q$-expansion coefficients. The real content of the Deligne--Tate result is that the converse is true.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler , could you elaborate it into an answer? I am a miserable mathematical physicist who does not understand algebraic geometry not over $\mathbb{C}$. I see a short discussion of the elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Z}((q))$ as a last section of Deligne's article cited above, but I don't know how to translate it back to the answer to my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rereading this, I realised I had misunderstood the question; I was reiterating the proof of something you already know (that the set of integral modular forms given by the "elliptic curves over $\mathbf{Z}$" definition is a subset of the "integral q-expansions" definition). The correct answer is the q-expansion principle as user175381 says.

Comment: Here is a maybe more accessible reference by Katz: https://dlculver.github.io/Katz-Lfunctions.pdf The version of the q-expansion principle that you need is on page 495. It remains to relate these algebraic modular forms to the "modular forms over Z" defined by Deligne-Tate, I don't have a reference for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it is a classic result, e.g. [a paper of Igusa](https://doi.org/10.2307/2373943) starts by stating this fact saying it's classic without citing any. A big more googling turned up that there's something called Victor Miller's basis which exactly does the job, implemented in Sage, see [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/modfrm/sage/modular/modform/vm_basis.html) and [here](https://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/level_one.html#the-miller-basis).

Let me present the proof here, which proceeds by induction in the degree.

Let $M_k$ be the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of modular forms of weight $k$, and $S_k$ be the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of cusp forms of weight $k$ (i.e. those which vanish at $q=0$). It is a standard fact that the multiplication by $\Delta$ gives an isomorphism $M_k \simeq S_{k+12}$.

We would like to prove that any element of $M_k$ whose $q$-expansion coefficients are all integral is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of monomials of $c_4$, $c_6$ and $\Delta$.

For $0\le k < 12$ this can be proved by inspection.

Now let us assume $k\ge 12$, and say $f\in M_k$ is a modular form with integral $q$-coefficients.
When $k$ is odd, $f=0$, and there is nothing to prove. When $k$ is even, there is a pair of nonnegative integers $(a,b)$ such that $c_4^a c_6^b \in M_k$.
Writing $f=f_0 + f_1 q + f_2 q^2 + \cdots$,
we find $f-f_0 c_4^a c_6^b$ is in $S_k$ and also has integral $q$-expansion coefficients.
Dividing by $\Delta$, this gives an element $g\in M_{k-12}$ which has integral $q$-expansion coefficients such that $f=g\Delta + f_0 c_4^a c_6^b$. Applying the inductive hypothesis, we are done.